# payhere payment gateway integration in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, api, payment-gateway, payment

I'm trying to integrate **[PayHere](https://www.payhere.lk/)** payment gateway to my site which is built with **Laravel 5.5**. So as their [documentation](https://support.payhere.lk/api-&-mobile-sdk/payhere-checkout) I have integrate their api as below. I'm  testing with **sandbox credentials** in **live sever** .In here what I do is first pass the payment details via a  `<from>` *(as in their documentation )*

> .So when I make a transaction it works as it should be and I receive the
>   success mail from the payment gateway too.

But my problem is that **I cant fetch the notification which send from the payment gateway to check the payment status of my payment to update the db**. So I have wrote a simple code to check the payment status code . *( 2 - success / 0 - pending / -1 - canceled / -2 -failed / -3 -charged-back )*

So could anyone please help me to solve this. Please refer below sample codes that I have written to test the **payment gateway which is in a live server**

- [Payment Gateway api details](https://support.payhere.lk/api-&-mobile-sdk/payhere-checkout)
- Laravel version 5.5

**CheckOutController**

```
 public function notifyUrl(Request $request){

 //As their documentation
 $merchant_id = $request -> input('merchant_id');
 $order_id =  $request -> input('order_id');
 $payhere_amount =  $request -> input('payhere_amount');
 $payhere_currency =  $request -> input('payhere_currency');
 $status_code =  $request -> input('status_code');
 $md5sig =  $request -> input('md5sig');

 $merchant_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Replace with your Merchant Secret (Can be found on your PayHere account's Settings page)

 $local_md5sig = strtoupper (md5 ( $merchant_id . $order_id . $payhere_amount . $payhere_currency . $status_code . strtoupper(md5($merchant_secret)) ) );
// return $status_code;
if (($local_md5sig === $md5sig) AND ($status_code == 2) ){

 $newStatus = new Status();
 $newStatus ->status= 2;
 $newStatus ->save();

 }elseif(($local_md5sig === $md5sig) AND ($status_code == 0) ){

 $newStatus = new Status();
 $newStatus ->status= 0;
 $newStatus ->save();

 }elseif(($local_md5sig === $md5sig) AND ($status_code == -1) ){

 $newStatus = new Status();
 $newStatus ->status= -1;
 $newStatus ->save();

 }elseif(($local_md5sig === $md5sig) AND ($status_code == -2) ){

 $newStatus = new Status();
 $newStatus ->status= -2;
 $newStatus ->save();

 }elseif(($local_md5sig === $md5sig) AND ($status_code == -3) ){

 $newStatus = new Status();
 $newStatus ->status= -3;
 $newStatus ->save();

 }else{

 $newStatus = new Status();
 $newStatus ->status= 'Fail';
 $newStatus ->save();

 }
}

 public function cancelUrl(){
  return redirect()->route('shop.home'); 
 }
 public function returnUrl(){
  return redirect()->route('shop.cart'); 
 }
```

**Routes**

```
$router //**using POST method hens they pass data via this url**
    -> post ( 'payment/notify' , 'CheckOutController@notifyUrl' )
    -> name ( 'shop.notifyUrl' ) ;

$router 
    -> get ( 'payment/cancelUrl' , 'CheckOutController@cancelUrl' )
    -> name ( 'shop.cancelUrl' ) ;

$router
    -> get ( 'payment/returnUrl' , 'CheckOutController@returnUrl' )
    -> name ( 'shop.returnUrl' ) ;
```

**Checkout Form** Sample taken from their documentation

```
<form method="post" action="https://sandbox.payhere.lk/pay/checkout" >  

            <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="000000">    <!-- Replace your Merchant ID -->
            <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{{route ( 'shop.returnUrl' )}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="{{route ( 'shop.cancelUrl' )}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{{route ( 'shop.notifyUrl' )}}">  

            <input hidden type="text" name="order_id" value="xxxxx">
            <input hidden type="text" name="items" value="xxxxxx">
            <input hidden type="text" name="currency" value="LKR">
            <input hidden type="text" name="amount" value="5000.0"> 

            <br><br>Customer Details</br></br>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" value="xxxxx">
            <input type="text" name="last_name" value="xxxx">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="xxxx">
            <input type="text" name="phone" value="xxxx">
            <input type="text" name="address" value=" xxxxx / xxxxxx/ xxxxxx/ Sri Lanka">
            <input type="text" name="city" value="Colombo">
            <input type="hidden" name="country" value="Sri Lanka">  
        </form>
```

> Update 01 (As @RicardoAlbear said )

[image: update]

Comment: One first recommendation i uses often is ensure the platform is sending the webhook in the correct way, to do that, i usually use this site https://webhook.site and set the generate url in the provider, so when you execute a payment, you will see all the details of the webhook in this site. Feel free to copy the result so i can help you then.

Comment: @RicardoAlbear Thank you very much for your comment . Could you please check the updated question please.

Comment: Did you have error logging enabled on Laravel? there you can see what's happening when your app receives the payment gateway callback.

Comment: @RicardoAlbear it dosent show any error. Looks like my notity url has something wrong. But I cant figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help from [payhere](https://www.payhere.lk/) I was able to fix my issue. The problem was I have not excluded the CSRF for my payhere notification url.So that laravel automatically reject the data passed through the notification url. So what I did was just added * (accept all the url s . Also we can specify the url like 'www.exapmle.com/payhere/nofity') and now its working. So the issue is that we need to exclude CSRF for payhere notify url. @RecardoAlbear thank you very much for your support. I was able to grab lot of new things from your comment. Thanks

**For future references payhere can be integrate as follow in Laravel**

1. Make your payhere account and obtain a merchant_id
2. As in the [documentation](https://support.payhere.lk/api-&-mobile-sdk/payhere-checkout) follow the steps
3. Exclud CSRF protection from `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`

   ```
     <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware ;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware ;

   class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
   {

       /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
     //I have used * - means that it allows for all the url. But you can specify excluded url s as you wanted 
           protected $except = [
                '*', //this exclude all urls
                'www.exapmle.com/payhere/nofity'
              ] ;
     }
   ```

Comment: Nice one +1. Thanks for the solution update.